# executar comando grep em linguagem C e retornar resultado

Tags: c, grep

```
void main()
{
    char comando[2000];
    char resultado[500]
    sprintf(comando, "grep '[0-9]{50}-' input.txt);
    resultado = system(comando);

    printf("%s\n",resultado);
}
```

Preciso apenas de 1 coincidência, e retornar o valor em resultado, o código acima não compila, é apenas um exemplo de como gostaria que ficasse.

Comment: É apenas um exemplo de como gostaria que funcionasse, o que eu não consigo é pegar o retorno do comando grep, até a parte de sprintf creio que esta correto

Comment: Você deve prover um exemplo funcional que reproduza o problema. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Desculpe Gabriel, mas se fosse funcional eu não estaria perguntando. Fiz um prototipo de como gostaria que fosse, para tentar explicar o problema. Não consigo obter resultado da chama system() se existir outra ou outra forma de fazer isso ficaria muito grato.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *mode);
int pclose(FILE *stream);

int main(void)
{
FILE *cmd;
char result[1024];

cmd = popen("grep bar /usr/share/dict/words", "r");
if (cmd == NULL) {
perror("popen");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
while (fgets(result, sizeof(result), cmd)) {
printf("%s", result);
}
pclose(cmd);
return 0;
}
```

Era exatamente isso que estava procurando. Obrigado.